# Show only text in Notification without any icon

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I want to show a notification that only shows a text instead of an icon!

I just try it as:

```
private void showNotification(String msg) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //set the notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)   
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        Log.e("xmn", exp.toString());
}
}
```

The problem is that the notification never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Android [requires](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) you to have the following content in your notification:

- A small icon, set by setSmallIcon()
- A title, set by setContentTitle()
- Detail text, set by setContentText()

So you must show an icon in your notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoteViews to set your custom layout/just a textview or anything.
[custom notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification)